# Variable number of quantifiers (as in $\exists n \exists x_1 \ldots \exists x_n$)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

In mathematics we casually use expresions with variable number of quantifiers, like
$$\forall a \in A\ \exists n \in \mathbb{N}\ \exists b_1,\ldots,b_n \in B\ \ \ a = b_1 + \cdots + b_n.$$
I'm wondering what is the formal status of such expressions. Is this just a convenient notation for second-order formulas? Because I guess $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}\ \exists b_1,\ldots,b_n \in B$ could be switched to $\exists S \subseteq B, |S|<\infty$.

I'd like to know what is the logical basis for these expressions.

Comment: $\exists b_1\dots b_n$ means $\exists b_1\dots\exists b_n$. Thus, $\exists b_1\dots\exists b_n\in B$ is an abbreviation for more formal $\exists b_1\in B\dots\exists b_n\in B$

Comment: I know that. My question was about the fact that there is an undetermined number of these quantifiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see $b_1, \dots, b_n$ as a function from an index set $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ to $B$, then it's an abbreviation for
$$\forall a \in A \;\exists n \in {\mathbb N} \;\exists b \colon \{1, 2, \dots, n\} \to B \;\; [a = \textstyle\sum_{i=1}^n b(i)].$$
(And this is not equivalent to
$$\forall a \in A \; \exists S \subseteq B \;\;[ |S| < \infty \land a = \textstyle\sum S],$$
because in the first formulation the $b_i$ can be repeated).

Comment: I see, thank you.